# How to Avoid Nausea During Flight Landing?

Tags: air-travel, health

Recently I started feeling nausea from the descent until landing. This happened on 5 of 6 flights which I have taken this month. I do not feel nausea during the rest of the flight. Flights have not caused me to feel motion sickness before - nor do trains - but every other mode of transportation does. Boats  make me dizzy and vomit in minutes and even cruises, buses and cars (unless driving) make me nauseous after a short while.

Is it common to feel nausea only during flights landing? Why does start happening?

**What can be done to prevent this?**

Comment: Have you tried the usual over-the-counter remedies for motion sickness?  Motion sickness is often more noticeable during descent because of more maneuvering of the airplane and winds / clouds that cause turbulence, and it sounds like you do suffer motion sickness in general.  Otherwise, this is probably a question for your doctor.

Comment: Yes, I do suffer from motion sickness, so I usually take Gravol before taking boats but it only slightly delays the reaction. Ginger is similar but it's effect lasts even less than the Gravol. I have asked around in Canada and Ecuador many times for alternatives but was told those are the only ones available here. I have not tried for the flights yet since this is a new symptom for me.

Comment: If this is a recent development and only in one stage of flight, you should probably consult a GP then an Otolaryngologist (ENT) to rule out medical condition.

Comment: Scopolamine ("scop") patches is what many sailors & scuba divers use.  However, it's not available everywhere.

Comment: @jpatokal beware of scopolamine: it's a mild hallucinogenic.

Comment: @jpatokal - Indeed, I've heard of those but never seen them. I will try to ask at my next destinations since I have 3 international flights next week.

Comment: This just stopped happening. Didn't happen in 5 flights over the last two weeks, so we won't know what that was for a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take over the counter nausea medicine.

If wanting to go more "natural" chew on ginger candies (or anything ginger you can have access to)

Ginger helps against motion sickness.

http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/nutrition-and-healthy-eating/in-depth/seo/art-20267062

Comment: That works if using the right medication Normally Gravol doesn't go much for me but in this case, it was enough.